# Convert Json string to Json object in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I try to convert JSON string to a JSON object but after JSONSerialization the output is nil in JSON.

Response String:

```
{
 "resultCount":50, 
 "results": [
{
"screenshotUrls":[ "1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"], 
"ipadScreenshotUrls":[ "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg"], 
"features":["iosUniversal"], 
"supportedDevices":["iPhone5s-iPhone5s", "iPhone13-iPhone13"], 
"kind":"software", 
"genres":["Food & Drink", "Travel"]}, 

{
"screenshotUrls":[....
```

I try to convert this string with my code below:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=yepp&entity=software")!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
            
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            

            let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? ResponseDataModel

            print(json)
        }
```

**ResponseDataModel**
This is the model I made.

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - ResponseDataModel
struct ResponseDataModel: Codable {
    let resultCount: Int
    let results: [Result]
}

// MARK: - Result
struct Result: Codable {
    let screenshotUrls, ipadScreenshotUrls: [String]
    let features: [String]
    let supportedDevices: [String]
    let kind: String
    let genres: [String]

}
```

Comment: When using Codable, you’d want to use JSONDecoder instead of JSONSerialization. See https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/119/codable-cheat-sheet

Comment: JSONSerialization will return usually an NSDictionary or NSArray. You are not printing the result of JSONSerialization which is likely not nil, but the result of trying to convert it to a ResponseDataModel, which will obviously fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSONDecoder, you could also create a class Encodable, Decodable, declaring coding keys, also Try this (I save a lot of time):

https://app.quicktype.io/#l=swift

best regards!